# redirecting file request for subdomain and main site with certain arguments?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am running wildcard subdomains. the aim of the site is to run a virtual subdomain. what the functionality should be is that when the files
 from the main site are called they will be rewritten for the clean URLs. But when i am calling the same files form the subdomain 
like xyz.doamin.com/my-file.php then this should be rewritten like it is calling that file with an argument of subdoamin like 
domain.com/my-file.php?var=xyz. Currently what i have done for the file call is this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

## Redirecting all non-www domains to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?var=%1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&var=%1 [L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com/index.php?subdomain=%1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&subdomain=%1 [L]
```

This is throwing a 500 internal error for the file call.

Answer (score 0):

Rule set 4 will overlap with rule set 1 and 2. I suspect this is causing the issue.
So I think all 3 need an extra `RewriteCond` check on `REQUEST_URI`.

Really you shouldn't need rule set 4. Just including index.php as a default should do the trick. Unless of course you don't want URL's like `http://www.domain.com/?var=xyz`, in this case you need rule 4, but you need to split it into 2 - one with a `QUERY_STRING` and one without, just like rule 1 and 2

Also, isn't `%1` from the regex in the rewriteRule itself and not the preceeding rewriteConds? If so then your regex is wrong, because it'll be setting the `var=` to the entire original URL.

Looking in the error log is a good idea as it will give you the reason for the 500 error.

Edit: Ok, try something like this (not tested)

```
## Redirecting all non-www domains to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

## Redirecting / requests to index.php
# Note: Use the QSA flag for handling with or without query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com/index.php?var=%1 [L,QSA]

## Redirecting /something requests to index.php
# Note: Use the QSA flag for handling with or without query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?var=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The Error Log has this line :: mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.,

Comment: Yep, that'll be your RuleSet 4. It never changes the `HTTP_HOST` and so will constantly match on its result. As I said you're best off ditching it entirely.

Comment: `@Sodved` See the Edited Code. Did u mean this?

Comment: Ruleset 2 and 4 still overlap. As do Ruleset 3 and 5. The have the exact same conditions.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve. WHere do you want them to end up. `http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?var=%1` or `http://www.domain.com/index.php?subdomain=%1`

Comment: The call from a subdomain like xyz.domain.com should Rewrite to access the index.php file with the subdomain in the arguments like index.php?var=xyz and the calls to files from the subdomain should go to the same file with the arguments of var=xyz (or what every subdomain is ) like xyz.domain.com/file.php should be rewritten in the HTACCESS like domain.com/file.php?var=xyz but for www.domain.com/file.php it should not pass the var Argument.